# Print JSON data through AJAX call in Rails and AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, json

New to Rails,
I have a Ruby application in my home_controller.erb which returns a JSON value from MongoDB and I have stored in @tuple Variable.

How can I print the JSON response on the Front end. Any help would be great.

tuple={"_id":{"$oid":"565a8bf88ab8dc1cc6000006"},"zip":"85009"}

This is my controller code:

```
  class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index



   uri='mongodb://heroku_bv2wfp7x:bt1uo8ddu73rs5p6b9nvk5tp4u@ds051534.mongolab.com:51534/heroku_bv2wfp7x'

   connection_variable=Mongo::Client.new(uri)


connection_variable[:mongoearthquakes].drop
puts "Connected to Mongo DataBase, Inserting data . . . . . "

$j=0

while $j < 9 do
// inserting data into MongoDB
    $j+=1
end



result=connection_variable[:mongoearthquakes].find()

result.each do |tuple|
    tuple=tuple.to_json

    puts tuple

    @data_to_be_printed=tuple
end


end
```

My index.html.erb file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Hello world: </p>
</div>  

<script>

      angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@data_to_be_printed",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
        console.log(@data_to_be_printed) 
    }        
});

}]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your ajax url needs to be something like `localhost:8000`

Comment: also all the logic needs to be in model

Comment: You can use  `MongoId`  for mongodb models

Comment: follow this link https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-mongoid-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Usually add

```
render json: @data_to_be_printed
```

as the last line of your `index` action will return JSON structure as you expected.

Comment: I am actually getting an error at URL. 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Am I accessing the JSON data from Controller in the right way?

Comment: I don't think it is correct. The url should be something like "http://localhost:3000" if you are running on your local environment and your root route is set as `index` in `HomeController`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the path in ajax should be the path in route.rb,  please also check the route first

In your index.html.erb

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: <%= home_index_path %>+".json",  
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    }
}
```

and add

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json  { render json: @data_to_be_printed }
end
```

in the index action of this home controller  -- home_controller.rb

Comment: So, my URL should point to the JSON value that is being returned?

Comment: I guess that's what your purpose. you should be able to see your home#index path by command `rake routes`